# How can I rearrange this table using SAS or MS-Access?

Tags: ms-access, sas

I have a dataset on Microsoft Access and SAS of about a million option prices arranged with the following fields/columns:

`DATE, COMPANY, PUT/CALL, PRICE`

The `PUT/CALL` variable is an indicator variable that comes out as either *PUT* or *CALL* for each unique *DATE-COMPANY* combination.

Example with numbers:

```
DATE             COMPANY          PUT/CALL       PRICE
2001/01/01       XOM              PUT            10
2001/01/01       XOM              CALL           12
2001/01/01       ABB              PUT            11
2001/01/01       ABB              CALL           13
```

What I need is for my table to be arranged with:

`DATE, COMPANY, PUT PRICE, CALL PRICE`

The above example with numbers, the output should be:

Example with numbers:

```
DATE             COMPANY          PUT PRICE      CALL PRICE
2001/01/01       XOM              10             12
2001/01/01       ABB              11             13
```

Would someone know how I could use SAS, Microsoft Access or any other software to complete this?

Answer (score 1):

In SAS this is pretty easy.

Assuming your first table is a dataset named 'HAVE', and is sorted by date/company:

```
proc transpose data=have out=want suffix=price;
by date company;
id put_call;
var price;
run;
```

In Access (or SQL) you'd want to do a SQL query, something like this:

```
create table want as select date,company,
 max(case when put_call='put' then price else null end) as put_price, 
 max(case when put_call='call' then price else null end) as call_price 
 from have group by date,company;
```

In SQL server you could probably do this with a pivot.

Comment: John Smith, you might notice that Joe used 'put_call' instead of 'put/call' as '/' is not a valid character in a SAS variable.

Comment: @probackpacker - your suggestion was a good one so I edited it in.  I suggest in the future though changes to answers should be made in the comments rather than as an edit, unless it's just formatting; unless I review it faster than the review queue watchers do, they'll almost always reject even very small changes if they are changing the code.

Comment: FYI, This was just discussed on [Meta] yesterday, here's the [Meta link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181082/what-is-the-position-of-meta-so-on-reviewing-answers/181085#181085).

Answer (score 1):

The following works in Access:

```
SELECT 
    [DATE], 
    [COMPANY], 
    MAX(IIf([PUT/CALL]="PUT", [PRICE], NULL)) AS [PUT PRICE], 
    MAX(IIf([PUT/CALL]="CALL", [PRICE], NULL)) AS [CALL PRICE] 
FROM [PRICES] 
GROUP BY [DATE], [COMPANY];
```

Note that...

- several of the column names have spaces or "funny characters" in them, and
- `DATE` is a reserved word in Access,

...so the square brackets `[]` are important.